# sql join, left join . records not shown if there's criteria for right table

Tags: sql, join, left-join

Table `a` fields:

```
id_a
```

Table `b` fields:

```
id_b
id_b2
filed_b
filed_b2
```

Table `c` fields:

```
id_c
filed_c
```

table `a` data:

```
id_a
----
1 
2
```

table `b` data:

```
id_b  id_b2  filed_b
----  -----  -------
1     1      1  
2     2      100
```

table `c` data:

```
id_c  filed_c
----  ---------
1     adfa11111
2     dfdf22222
```

**join**

```
a join b on id_a=id_b
b join c on id_b2=id_c
```

The goal is to get all table `a` data and associated `filed_c` data. 
Criterion is:  `if filed_b=100, list filed_c. otherwise leave filed_c null.`

Problem: used left join, if no criteria on the right table, it's fine. But once there's a criteria on right table, the records not exist in right table won't show up.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to get a where condition to work with a left outer join is to put the criteria in the join clause. If you checked against `b.filed_b` in the where clause you exclude the rows where the values is `null` which it is when there is no match in table `b`.

Something like this in your case.

```
select *
from a
  left outer join b
    on a.id_a = b.id_b and
       b.filed_b = 100
  left outer join c
    on b.id_b2 = c.id_c
```